# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' while loading keras model

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using a pretrained yolov4 keras model for object detection in tf2
So I loaded the model and call it like

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./checkpoints/yolov4-416')
pred_bbox = new_model(image_data)
for key, value in pred_bbox.items():
```

then an error occurred:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items'

So I modified my code

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./checkpoints/yolov4-416')
prediction_list = new_model.predict(image_data)
prediction_dict = {name: pred for name, pred in zip(new_model.output_names, prediction_list)}
for key, value in pred_bbox.items():
    boxes = value[:, :, 0:4]
    pred_conf = value[:, :, 4:] 

boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
    boxes=tf.reshape(boxes, (tf.shape(boxes)[0], -1, 1, 4)),
    scores=tf.reshape( pred_conf,
    (tf.shape(pred_conf)[0], -1, tf.shape(pred_conf)[-1])),
    max_output_size_per_class=50,
    max_total_size=50,
    iou_threshold=FLAGS.iou,
    score_threshold=FLAGS.score
)
pred_bbox = [boxes.numpy(), scores.numpy(), classes.numpy(), valid_detections.numpy()]
image = utils.draw_bbox(original_image, pred_bbox)
```

It was doing great until box.numpy() is called
and another error occurred

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

I wonder how to solve this, and I think it's because it is in graph mode instead of eager execution?

Comment: Yes. It's because of graph mode. But are you using tf1 or disabled eager mode in tf2 or using @tf.function?

Comment: i don't understand where did you called boxes.numpy()

Comment: As @BestDogeStackoverflow said, you may called `boxes.numpy()` where it may run in graph mode. So please add complete code.

Comment: @Kaveh I used tf2 and it should be eager mode in default

Comment: What is the exact version of tensorflow you are using ?

Comment: @jimmy12487 Yes. But you may use this in a function which execute in graph mode. For example, custom loss function, dataset map function etc.

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow I added my code, thank you so much for replying.

Comment: @Kishore tensorflow2.5.0

Comment: @Kaveh would you mind checking my code on github?

Comment: Could you check if you are getting the value you are expecting and its types for `boxes`, `scores` and `classes` before calling `boxes.numpy()` ?

Comment: @jimmy12487 Provide link.

Comment: @Kishore yes the difference is it's type should be 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' instead of 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'

Comment: @Kaveh https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite this is the pretrained model I use. But I trained some other pics additionally

Comment: If ultimately you want to just convert the Tensor to a numpy array, did you try `np.array(boxes)` ? I'm not sure if it will work though.

Comment: @Kishore yes but it fails, saying 'This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported'

Comment: @jimmy12487 I can't see any problem in the above code. I also ran the code on my PC, and it worked without any error. Make sure you are using tensorflow 2.

Answer (score 0):

OK I just kind of solve the problem
When I'm saving model, it's somehow saved in graph mode, which is why I can't call boxes.numpy().
So what I do is just load weights and rebuild the model and the problem is just gone.
But I still want to know what makes it wrong

save_model code:

```
STRIDES, ANCHORS, NUM_CLASS, XYSCALE = utils.load_config(FLAGS)
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input([FLAGS.input_size, FLAGS.input_size, 3])
feature_maps = YOLO(input_layer, NUM_CLASS, FLAGS.model, FLAGS.tiny)
bbox_tensors = []
prob_tensors = []
for i, fm in enumerate(feature_maps):
  if i == 0:
    output_tensors = decode(fm, FLAGS.input_size // 8, NUM_CLASS, STRIDES, ANCHORS, i, XYSCALE, FLAGS.framework)
  elif i == 1:
    output_tensors = decode(fm, FLAGS.input_size // 16, NUM_CLASS, STRIDES, ANCHORS, i, XYSCALE, FLAGS.framework)
  else:
    output_tensors = decode(fm, FLAGS.input_size // 32, NUM_CLASS, STRIDES, ANCHORS, i, XYSCALE, FLAGS.framework)
  bbox_tensors.append(output_tensors[0])
  prob_tensors.append(output_tensors[1])
pred_bbox = tf.concat(bbox_tensors, axis=1)
pred_prob = tf.concat(prob_tensors, axis=1)
boxes, pred_conf = filter_boxes(pred_bbox, 
  pred_prob,`score_thershold=FLAGS.score_thres, 
  input_shape=tf.constant([FLAGS.input_size, FLAGS.input_size]))
  pred = tf.concat([boxes, pred_conf], axis=-1)
model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, pred)
utils.load_weights(model, FLAGS.weights, FLAGS.model, FLAGS.tiny)
model.summary()
model.save(FLAGS.output)
```